# What is this type of normalization called? When to use it?

Tags: data-transformation, normalization

I want to know if there is a name for this type of normalization (maybe it cannot be described as normalization?):

```
( 1 - X ) / X
```

The resulting function is an exponential decay. When would you want to use a normalization like this?

**Edit based on question:**

It was used on a simulation of a phenotype based on genomic data:

`y = g + e`

where `y` is the phenotype for example height and `g` is a genetic value for each individual (not important here how they generated it ).

The residuals effects `e` were generated from a `N (0, var(g) * (1 - x) / x )`

Where x is the heritability of the phenotype and it is expressed as a proportion.

Comment: $(1-x)/x = \frac{1}{x} -1$ is not exponential. It's a branch of a hyperbola. In what context did you see this? Was $x$ a proportion, for example?

Comment: This was in a paper? $\text{var}(g)\frac{x}{1-x}$ looks like it might come from an approximation to a variance of a transformed variable via [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) of the transformation about the mean

Comment: This would ordinarily be called a "transformation" or "re-expression" of $x$ rather than a "normalization".  It makes the most sense when $x$ is constrained to lie between $0$ and $1$, in which case this particular re-expression is often called the "odds" (which literally is what it is when $x$ represents a probability).  It is more commonly expressed in terms of its logarithm, the "log odds" or "logit."